# Xbox 360 Controller not working with PC

Tags: usb, xbox360, controller

I have installed the 360 controller software from Microsoft and it comes up in device manager but the controller software does not recognize the device.

---

Compatibility Report from Device Manager:

Issues found 
Xbox 360 Wireless Controller via Play & Charge Kit can’t work properly with USB 3.0.Xbox 360 Wireless Controller via Play & Charge Kit can’t work properly with USB 3.0.
If the USB 2.0 device is incompatible with USB 3.0, plugging it into a USB 2.0 port can solve the problem. Not fixed Not Fixed 
Xbox 360 Wireless Controller via Play & Charge Kit is an older USB device and might not work with USB 3.0 Informational

User initiated troubleshooting on a USB deviceUser initiated troubleshooting on a USB device
Windows has scanned for common USB device problems. Detected Detected

Issues found Detection details

6 Xbox 360 Wireless Controller via Play & Charge Kit can’t work properly with USB 3.0. Not fixed Not Fixed

If the USB 2.0 device is incompatible with USB 3.0, plugging it into a USB 2.0 port can solve the problem.

---

The controller has been plugged both into a USB 2 and a USB 3 socket.
Any ideas?

Comment: Do you own an USB wireless adapter for this device?

Comment: I can confirm this adapter works when plugged into a USB 3.0 port sounds like the adapter failed it happens

Comment: @duDE I do not have a wireless reciever but I am using a play and charge kit. It does work on my 360

Comment: @Frames-PerGames - The charging cable just charges it sends no data.

Answer (score 2):

You need the 360 wireless receiver to use your wireless 360 controller with PC, cable or not.

Play and charge cable is only used to transmit power, not data. It works with Xbox because Xbox has the receiver built-in.

To quote Microsoft [support article](https://support.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-on-other-devices/windows/xbox-controller-for-windows-setup) on this issue:

> A standard Xbox 360 wireless controller can be connected to a Windows PC, but you must have an Xbox 360 Wireless Gaming Receiver to play games, even if you have an Xbox 360 Play & Charge Kit.